# Efficiency problem of customizing numpy's vectorized operation

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a python function given below:

```
def myfun(x):
    if x > 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return np.exp(x)
```

where `np` is the `numpy` library. I want to make the function vectorized in numpy, so I use:

```
vec_myfun = np.vectorize(myfun)
```

I did a test to evaluate the efficiency. First I generate a vector of 100 random numbers:

```
x = np.random.randn(100)
```

Then I run the following code to obtain the runtime:

```
%timeit np.exp(x)

%timeit vec_myfun(x)
```

The runtime for `np.exp(x)` is `1.07 µs ± 24.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)`.

The runtime for `vec_myfun(x)` is `71.2 µs ± 1.68 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)`

My question is: compared to `np.exp`, `vec_myfun` has only one extra step to check the value of $x$, but it runs much slowly than `np.exp`. Is there an efficient way to vectorize `myfun` to make it as efficient as `np.exp`?

Comment: Did you see this note: "The `vectorize` function is provided primarily for convenience, not for
performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.
"?

Comment: `np.exp` is compiled code; your function is Python, and `vectorize` just iterates through `x` passing scalar values to your function.  So the loop is at the slower Python level.

Comment: @hpaulj Just see this note. From the runtime comparison I guessed that that `np.vectorize` iterates through `x` to compute the result without using the compiled code. I am looking for an implementation to make it as efficient as the compiled code.

Comment: You could do this entirely with `np.exp`, using its `out` and `where` parameters.

Comment: You can use Numba's vectorize https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html This outperforms a call to np.exp by about a factor of two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ufunc` like `np.exp` have a `where` parameter, which can be used as:

```
In [288]: x = np.random.randn(10)
In [289]: out=np.zeros_like(x)
In [290]: np.exp(x, out=out, where=(x<=0))
Out[290]: 
array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.09407685,
       0.92458328, 0.        , 0.        , 0.46618914, 0.        ])
In [291]: x
Out[291]: 
array([ 0.37513573,  1.75273458,  0.30561659,  0.46554985, -2.3636433 ,
       -0.07841215,  2.00878429,  0.58441085, -0.76316384,  0.12431333])
```

This actually skips the calculation where the `where` is false.

In contrast:

```
np.where(arr > 0, 0, np.exp(arr))
```

calculates `np.exp(arr)` first for all `arr` (that's normal Python evaluation order), and then performs the `where` selection.  With this `exp` that isn't a big deal, but with `log` it could be problems.

Answer (score 3):

Use `np.where`:

```
>>> x = np.random.rand(100,)
>>> %timeit np.exp(x)
1.22 µs ± 49.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
>>> %timeit np.where(x > 0, 0, np.exp(x))
4.09 µs ± 282 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

For comparison, your vectorized function runs in about 30 microseconds on my machine.

As to why it runs slower, it's just much more complicated than `np.exp`. It's doing lots of type deduction, broadcasting, and possibly making many calls to the actual method. Much of this happens in Python itself, while nearly everything in the call to `np.exp` (and the `np.where` version here) is in C.

Answer (score 1):

Just thinking outside of the box, what about implementing a function `piecewise_exp()` that basically multiplies `np.exp()` with `arr < 0`?

```
import numpy as np


def piecewise_exp(arr):
    return np.exp(arr) * (arr < 0)
```

Writing the code proposed so far as functions:

```
@np.vectorize
def myfun(x):
    if x > 0:
        return 0.0
    else:
        return np.exp(x)


def bnaeker_exp(arr):
    return np.where(arr > 0, 0, np.exp(arr))
```

And testing that everything is consistent:

```
np.random.seed(0)


# : test that the functions have the same behavior
num = 10
x = np.random.rand(num) - 0.5

print(x)
print(myfun(x))
print(piecewise_exp(x))
print(bnaeker_exp(x))
```

Doing some micro-benchmarks for small inputs:

```
# : micro-benchmarks for small inputs
num = 100
x = np.random.rand(num) - 0.5

%timeit np.exp(x)
# 1.63 µs ± 45.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
%timeit myfun(x)
# 54 µs ± 967 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit bnaeker_exp(x)
# 4 µs ± 87.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit piecewise_exp(x)
# 3.38 µs ± 59.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

... and for larger inputs:

```
# : micro-benchmarks for larger inputs
num = 100000
x = np.random.rand(num) - 0.5

%timeit np.exp(x)
# 32.7 µs ± 1.78 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit myfun(x)
# 44.9 ms ± 1.17 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit bnaeker_exp(x)
# 481 µs ± 25.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit piecewise_exp(x)
# 149 µs ± 2.65 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

This shows that `piecewise_exp()` is faster than anything else proposed so far, especially for larger inputs for which `np.where()` gets more inefficient since it uses integer indexing instead of boolean masks, and reasonably approaches `np.exp()` speed.

## EDIT

Also, the performances of the `np.where()` version (`bnaeker_exp()`) do depend on the number of elements of the array actually satisfying the condition. If none of them does (like when you test on `x = np.random.rand(100)`), this is slightly faster than the boolean array multiplication version (`piecewise_exp()`) (`128 µs ± 3.26 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)` on my machine for `n = 100000`).

Comment: I tested your method for large `num`. I think your method is more efficient when there are few elements satisfying the condition `arr<0`. Otherwise `bnaeker_exp(x)` works better. BTW, did you use some accelerating libraries (if exists) for `numpy`?  Why your `np.exp(x)` is so efficient when `num=100000`? I tested on my PC, my result for `piecewise_exp(x)` is 690 µs ± 10.5 µs while `np.exp(x)` is 546 µs ± 12.9 µs. Your `np.exp(x)` is nearly 5 times faster than `piecewise_exp(x)` and more than 10 times faster than `bnaeker_exp(x)`.

Comment: I think the combination with boolean array (`piecewise_exp()`) is more or less independent on the number of elements satisfying one condition or the other. The `np.where()` method instead depends a lot (at least on larger arrays) on how many elements are satisfying the condition. In the extreme case (i.e. when all numbers are positive), `np.where()` may be faster since it has no elements to operate to (and in that case it may be slightly faster than `piecewise_exp()`). Testing on a 50% hit array seems the logical thing to do to me, unless you have other info.

Comment: Regarding the raw speed of `np.exp()`, I have `numpy` / `scipy` installed through `conda` if that matters. I believe it depends if you have `numexpr` installed (or not). Beyond some certain size, I think it uses that by default.