# how to fix numpy log inf values and RuntimeWarning

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am calculating free energy G = -RT ln(1-Y/Y)

Y is a numpy ndarray

problem is when element of Y = 1 or 0.

```
try:
    log_value = np.log((1-Y)/Y)
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    log_value = -1
except RuntimeWarning:
    log_value = 1

Z = -0.0083145*X*log_value
```

if Y = 1 ln gives Runtime error and value as -inf (i want ln to return 1)

if Y = 0 ln gives ZeroDivisionError: (i want ln to return -1)

Comment: `np.log` is a `ufunc`, as such it accepts a `where` and `out` parameters.  Those can be used to bypass these warnings and undesired values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52622172/numpy-where-function-can-not-avoid-evaluate-sqrtnegative, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52472531/efficiency-problem-of-customizing-numpys-vectorized-operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after doing np.log I have simply added

```
temp_log = np.log((1-Y)/Y)
temp_log[temp_log==-np.inf] = 1
temp_log[temp_log==-0] = -1
Z = -0.0083145*X*temp_log
```

this replaces all values that are not acceptable by me in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the errors, anticipate them in advance:

```
if Y == 1:
    log_value = 1
elif Y == 0:
    log_value = -1
else:
    log_value = np.log((1-Y)/Y)


Z = -0.0083145*X*log_val
```